# Asp.net (VB) Buttons do not fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, button, click

All my buttons under my aspx page do not fire. Even if events are assigned to them:

```
button_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button.Click
```

Also, I've tried to assign an event directly by using OnClick attribute... and I got an error...

One more thing. Formely, this project was under .Net 1.1 framework. Since, It has been migrated to 4.0. The weirdest thing is, into some other pages, all buttons work perfectly...

Any Suggestion?

Here are the specs:

- VB.Net 2010
- Using Codebehind
- Framework 4
- ASP.Net

Comment: you've named a button `button`?  VB.NET isn't case sensitive... although this probably isn't related, it is still a bad idea (you hide the base class `Button` in doing so).

Comment: What error did you get on your OnClick?

Comment: Hard to tell without actually seeing it on my machine...few things to double check: is the code behind file referenced correctly, double/triple check that ID's of buttons are correct, compare this page to those of pages that are working, what's different?

Comment: could you post the html where your button is declared and your full `<@ Page >` tag?

Comment: Check the AutoEventWireUp attribute and make sure it's set to true?

Answer (score 0):

I would also check if there are any validators on the page. If you don't have a validation summary or visible error message it might not be apparent that you have triggered a validator that is preventing the page from submitting.